# VS 2015 C# AsyncExtension.cs not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I haven't been able to find any information on this online. I'm debugging an console application, trying to step through some code. When I go to step over I get a source not found error. It says "AsyncExtension.cs not found" and then gives me some details. It says "You need to find AsyncExtension.cs to view the source for the current call stack frame". I'm working in VS2015. I'm assuming something async is happening behind the scenes, its erroring at some point but can't give me the specific details because it can't find the assembly containing AsyncExtension. But I don't know what this is, where to get it, etc. The code in particular I'm trying to step over is below. But I seem to get this at various points, and even when debugging other projects under the same solution.

Line of code:

```
var newObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HIDPMessage>(message.ToString());
```

HIDPMessage:

```
public class HIDPMessage
    {
        public string version { get; set; }
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty]
        public string header { get; set; }
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty]
        private Data Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I seriously doubt `message.ToString()` produces JSON.  More likely it just returns the type name.

Comment: Yea your right. We have to do some more fenagling with it to get it into JSON format. I dont think the issue is with the deserialization though. Else I wouldnt get the error in other parts of the application.

Comment: Edit that part of your code so it's actually trying to deserialize actual, valid JSON and see if its still a problem.  I bet it won't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input guys, you were right my code for deserializing was a little off. It turns out this app was built using VS2017 and some components from the Azure SDK were missing. I tried a manual install of the SDK but it wouldn't work - upgrading to 2017 fixed it, but I'm kinda surprised I had to upgrade just to get it to work.

I appreciate the feedback on the serialization stuff as well. This is a new-ish area for me and I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but the code you have provided would not normally have any references to anything called AsyncExtension.cs. However your attempt to deserialize message could cause a JsonReaderException.

I'm guessing that "message" is some object that contains properties in common with HIDPMessage type and that you are trying to extract those into a new object, if so message.ToString(), unless overridden will just return the name of the type.

You need to serialize the object to a json string and use the json string instead of message.ToString();